# Unable to read data from the transport connections

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I need to consume a web service in C# but to do so requires authentication. When trying to call the service, I get this error:

> *UNABLE TO READ DATA FROM THE TRANSPORT CONNECTION. AN EXISTING CONNECTION WAS FORCIBLY CLOSED BY THE REMOTE HOST*

If I consume the web service in SoapUI, I can call it. But I have to assign the wss-password type by Password Text. If not assigned it gives me error

So not missing assign the password text at the time of consumption on c#

Thanks